# JQuery effects behind the scenes

Tags: jquery

I'm learning some basics about JQuery. When I learn about something, I always try to imagine how works behind the scenes, but I don't imagine how some effects really are done.

For example some simple .hide(slow) is an example. As I understand, JQuery modifies HTML code of HTML components. A ".hide" without animation seems pretty "obvious", I guess "visibility:none" would do the trick.

But animation implies something more interesting I guess. The first idea is a loop that changes attributes and expect rendering is fast enough to make a smooth animation. But it sounds pretty "CPU abusive".

How it's really done?

Edit: I don't consider even an average JS programmer, so reading the original source code is quite difficut. I was looking for some "big picture" explanation. Maybe the word **really** wasn't appropiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's source code is a bit too high-level to understand easily, so it might be easier to just write a simple animation from scratch:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var maximum = 200;
var interval = 5;
var left = 10;

function animate() {
    if (left < maximum) {
        left += 1 - Math.pow(left / maximum, 5);
        element.style.left = left + 'px';

        setTimeout(animate, interval);
    }
}

animate();​
```

And a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QB8C7/3/.

jQuery does something similar, but in a much more structured manner.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification. I had that idea in mind, but I thought there could be some more "elegant" solution than killing the CPU (maybe using GPU?). Edit: Nice not linear effect using pow.

Comment: Browsers like Chrome do in fact use hardware acceleration and the GPU to do a lot of their rendering.

Comment: @Vic: From what I can tell, only `-webkit-transition` utilizes GPU acceleration. You can get a polyfill that automatically utilizes `transition` to animate elements using CSS3, but that isn't by default.

Comment: I didn't back up my (possibly false) claims with anything concrete, so I may possibly be wrong.

Comment: @peterRit - This sort of thing needn't kill the CPU. For your original example of `.hide('slow')`, a total of twenty "frames" of animation is enough to make it smooth. If you're only running a few animations at a time the CPU won't even notice...

Comment: Does jQuery make use of CSS3 animation if available or does it only use the `setTimeout` approach? CSS is hardware accelerated, so it makes sence for jQuery to use it if it can.

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien: I don't think so

Answer (score 2):

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.hide

There ya go. That site is fantastic for seeing what's under the bonnet for any jQuery function.

Editing my reply after your edit to your question--

Think about a movie. Let's say Harry Potter and a scene in which they have to make an actor [disapparate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disapparate). How would they do it? They would need to increase the actor's transparency every unit of time until transparency becomes 100%. In the case of hide(slow), let's say that's about 1000 milliseconds (I haven't bothered looking it up). So the object's transparency needs to go from 0% to 100% in 1 second. So they'd need to reduce transparency by 1% every 100th of a second to achieve that effect. This would be fairly cpu-intensive for your average Pentium 133 (I still have my computer from high school-- it'd be a good test to see how it responds), but not a modern processor. If you had a page filled with jQuery animations however, you'd start to notice the slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [source code on jQueries site](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js) to see *exactly* how it is done behind the scenes.

EDIT: For extra readability, check the [GitHub repo](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src).

Comment: Yes, GitHub should have been my first thought, much easier to read.